# Reload only gridview in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, pjax

How can I, reload only **grid-view** on **on change** event of drop-down in Yii2?

I know that it can be done via pjax but not sure where and how to use the code.

I am using **Ajax request** for communicating with controller. Here is the ajax code:-

```
function loadGrid(level) { 
    alert(level); 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'index.php?r=villagedata/level', 
        data: {level:level}, 
        success: function(data) 
        { 
            alert("Success"); 
            $.pjax({container: '#myview'}); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

I wan't my grid to reload when the **Ajax Request** returns success message.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly, using Pjax.

```
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-grid-view']); ?>    
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            '...'
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

and jQuery to detect drop down change.

If dropdown has "dropdown" id,

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function(ev) {
     $.pjax({container: '#pjax-grid-view'})
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But, the grid is not reloading.!

Comment: Is drop down change event called?

Comment: Yes. I am doing an ajax call to the controller, then performing some query on model returning it and then reloading only gridview, am i doing right?

Comment: You will update the gridview calling $.pjax({container: '#pjax-grid-view'})

Comment: function loadGrid(level) { alert(level);    
                          $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: 'index.php?r=villagedata/level',
                                data: {level:level},
                                success: function(data) {
                                    alert("Success");
                                    $.pjax({container: '#myview'});
                                }
                            });
                        }
After Success Message.

Comment: Reload only the grid view without reloding the whole page
                                            $.pjax.reload('#w0-pjax' , {timeout : false});

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#idyourgrid").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
```

Comment: i think this is just the same as the `location.reload` javascript.